# Implementing smooth div toggle

Tags: jquery

I am trying to recreate the "div toggle" effect on this page, but with jQuery:

cordon-bleu.se

I want this effect, but working like the above page: the visible div hides when you click to show another:

sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/

My javascript so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("h2.menutrigger").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active').slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).next().addClass('active').slideToggle("slow");
 });

});
```

These are the divs I am trying to toggle:

```
<div class="menuitem active">
 <img src="images/img_header.png" style="margin: 15px auto;"/>
</div>
<h2 class="menutrigger"><a href="#">Historia</a></h2>
<div class="menuitem">
 <p>Bla bla</p>
 <p>Bla Bla</p>
</div>
<h2 class="menutrigger"><a href="#">Spisar</a></h2>
<div class="menuitem">
 <p>Bla bla</p>
</div>
```

And this is my (relevant) css:

```
.menuitem {
 height: 385px;
 background-color: #000;
 display:none;
}

.active {
 display: block;
}
```

You can see [here](http://rutinerad.com/projekt/cb_test/) how it works right now.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Do you need to create it again?  You're basically creating the jQuery UI Accordion :) http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/  If you're doing just a very lightweigt/simple version I'm all for it, just letting you know there are various accordions already out there, the jQuery UI one is one of many.

Comment: I agree with Nick, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, but its not easy to find when you don't know what your looking for and where to look :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to remove the `display: block;` statement from your `.active` class and let jQuery handle the display setting for you via `slideToggle()`.